# how to flatten a cirq.Circuit with CircuitOperation

Tags: programming, quantum-circuit, cirq

I have a `cirq.Circuit` that uses a `CircuitOperation`, something like:

```
circuit = cirq.Circuit(cirq.CircuitOperation(cirq.X.on(q), repetitions=5))
```

How can I flatten this circuit to remove the CircuitOperation and just have the moments?

Comment: Have you tried mapped_circuit with deep=True? https://quantumai.google/cirq/build/circuits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One "hacky" way to do it is to convert it to/from qasm. For example:

```
import cirq
from cirq.contrib.qasm_import import circuit_from_qasm

q = cirq.NamedQubit("q")
circuit = cirq.Circuit(
    cirq.Y(q),
    cirq.CircuitOperation(cirq.FrozenCircuit(cirq.X(q)), repetitions=5),
    cirq.Z(q)
)

circuit_flat = circuit_from_qasm(circuit.to_qasm())

print(circuit)
print(circuit_flat)
```

```
q: ───Y───[ q: ───X─── ](loops=5)───Z───

q_0: ───Y───X───X───X───X───X───Z───
```

**EDIT:**

A better way is to use [cirq.expand_composite](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/expand_composite):

> A transformer that expands composite operations via `cirq.decompose`.
>
> For each operation in the circuit, this pass examines if the operation can be decomposed. If it can be, the operation is cleared out and replaced with its decomposition using a fixed insertion strategy.
>
> Transformation is applied using `cirq.map_operations_and_unroll`, which preserves the moment structure of the input circuit.

Continuing from the example above:

```
circuit_flat2 = cirq.expand_composite(circuit)

print(circuit_flat2)
```

```
q: ───Y───X───X───X───X───X───Z───
```